# Run grunt from node:13:7 docker image?

Tags: docker, gruntjs, npm-scripts

I have this entry in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
npm:
    image: node:13.7
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']
```

And I would like to be able to run `grunt`

I did:

```
docker-compose run --rm npm install grunt --save-dev
```

But it seems `grunt-cli` must be installed globally...

It is possible to have something like `npm run grunt install`?

Comment: Installing Node on the host is pretty easy; why not just use Node directly, instead of trying to route things via Docker?

Comment: Because the point of using docker is to not install anything on the host :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply install `grunt` and `grunt-cli` locally !

```
docker-compose run --rm npm install grunt --save-dev
docker-compose run --rm npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
```

Then add a script in your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {      
  "grunt": "grunt <task>",
```

... where `<task>` is the task you want to run.